# Check if table has RANGE partition

Tags: sql, impala, apache-kudu

Is it possible to list type of partitions(`HASH`,`RANGE` etc) applied on a given Kudu table through a query? I need to check if that table contains `RANGE` partition or not.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Kudu's official documentation carefully, I found the way to check the structure of the table. We can use this query to get the list of partitions and the overall table structure:

```
show create table <table_name>;
```

And to get list of all the partitions on that table use:

```
show partitions <table_name>;
```